# Using HTML variable in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, sqlite

I'm trying to use the value stored in token in my PHP script to update a database value with SQLite.  It wont let me use document.getElementByID....any ideas?

```
<div id="TokenCount">
<label for="token"><abbr title="Tokens">Tokens</abbr></label>
<input id="token" value="0" />
</div>

<div id="Buttons">
<button id="pay" onClick="pay(10); loadMessage()"><?php $db=sqlite_open("../../logins.db"); 
$token = document.getElementById('token').value;
sqlite_query($db,"UPDATE Users SET tokens='$token' WHERE user_id='{$_SESSION['user_id']}'"); 
sqlite_close($db); ?>Pay</button> 
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: you can't execute server code on client side

Comment: `PHP` is server-side, `Javascript` (and `getElementByID`) is client-side. You cannot mix them in such manner.

Comment: Use `AJAX` to pass Javascript value to PHP script

Comment: in my .js file I have:     document.getElementById('token').value = new_token;
    return new_token;   new_token is also the value that I want to use to update my database value....how do I use AJAX to do that?  do I do it in the .js file still?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference: Why does the PHP (or other server side) code in my Javascript not work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/reference-why-does-the-php-or-other-server-side-code-in-my-javascript-not-wor)

Comment: @user3553438 see my example

Answer (score 0):

PHP code is executed server-side, so the website is sent to the client with the result of the PHP code without any PHP found in the source. Because of this HTML tags cannot be used in PHP on a website.

Answer (score 0):

As i said in comments, you can't execute PHP-code(server side code) on client side (in browser).

You should send [AJAX query](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to server, and save this value to mysql on server side.

Javascript(jquery) code:

```
function loadMessage(){
    $.post("setValue.php", {val:document.getElementById('token').value} function( data ) {
       alert('success');
    });
}
```

Create new php script for example setValue.php (r use contoller action, or your own staff how you routing pages). Script code:

```
$token = $_POST['val'];
sqlite_query($db,"UPDATE Users SET tokens='$token' WHERE user_id='{$_SESSION['user_id']}'"); 
sqlite_close($db);
```

Comment: **Danger**: You are **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)**

Comment: Hi Alex,
where do I put the top bit?  in the HTML or in the .js file?  Is it a function called data that then needs to be called?

Comment: first part - js, this function you should call on button click, second - php script that will be called by ajax-query and will save value

Comment: @Alex — That doesn't make it a good idea to put security holes in your answers.

Comment: @Quentin you think i should lecture about PDO and csrf in this answer?

Comment: @Alex - I'm not worried about security at the moment...just need to get it to work the simplest way. Alex, when you say call by ajax-query...what do you mean? I've put: <button id="pay" onClick="pay(10); loadMessage(); data()">Pay</button>

Comment: @Alex - Hi Alex, I'm so sorry...thank you for all your help but I still cant get it to work...i've done the following:

Comment: @Alex - .js file Ive put this function in:
function loadTokens(){
    $.post("updateTokens.php", {val:document.getElementById('token').value} function( data ) {
       alert('success');
    });
}

Comment: @Alex - the updateTokens.php file contains only this:
<?php
$db=sqlite_open("../../logins.db"); 
$token = $_POST['val'];
sqlite_query($db,"UPDATE Users SET tokens='$token' WHERE user_id='{$_SESSION['user_id']}'"); 
sqlite_close($db);
?>

Comment: @Alex - and I call the function in the HTML file like this:
        <button id="pay" onClick="pay(10); loadMessage(); loadTokens()">Pay</button>

Comment: @Alex - no error, but when my HTML page loads, it's like it's ignoring the whole .js file?  If I remove the new function, it works again.  And it isnt changing the value stored in the table

Comment: sorry, but you should learn debug your code - use console (F12) in web browser, and var_dump in php.

Comment: @Alex - function loadTokens(){ $.post("updateTokens.php", {val:document.getElementById('token').value} function( data ) { alert('success'); }); }

it expects a ) and a ; before function(data) and it says that $ is undefined.  And sorry I didnt realise I could do the f12 thing....v new to this

Comment: @Alex - if I add the ); before the function(data) then the .js file loads and everything else works as normal...but it still says the $ is undefined?

Comment: add to header <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>